# Variable passed to a function giving unexpected value

Tags: c++

When I pass an integer to the function below via a variable (ie x=1 `PrintAccntInfo( x, bank_name)`   it is always read as 0 by the function regardless of its actual value. However, if I type in the value directly ie `PrintAccntInfo(1, bank_name)` the function works fine. Can someone explain to me what is going on here? Thanks!

```
void Bank::PrintAccntInfo(int accntnum, Bank bank_name) {
    int num_transactions = 0;
    transaction_node *temp;
    temp = bank_name.accounts[accntnum].head;
    .......
```

accntnum is the problem.

Edit:

Here is the code I call the function from (resp is a string read in from the user):

```
    if (stoi(resp)) {
                        int resp_int = stoi(resp);

                        if (resp_int = 0) {
                            for (int i=1;i<21;i++)  //print all the account transactions                    
                                PrintAccntInfo(i,our_bank);
                            badinputchk = false;
                        } else {
                            PrintAccntInfo(resp_int,our_bank);
                            badinputchk = false;
                        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show the code where you set the variable and call PrintAccntInfo?

Comment: If you think the *caller* of this isn't important, you're wrong.

Comment: @nurettin Ok, I've added it in.

Comment: @Adam you see the error in your if statement, right? x= 0 is not x== 0

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you always get 0 in function is that condition

```
if (resp_int = 0)
```

sets `resp_int` to 0 and evaluates to `false`, so it always goes inside "else" where the function is invoked with resp_int(which is 0)

You should replace it with `if (resp_int == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the value of the x is out of the scope. It's better you can show how do you call the function PrintAccntInfo() and the definition of the x.

Comment: Ok, I've added in the code. Would you mind having another look?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that variables have "scope".

```
int i = 10;

int func(int i) {
    if (i > 0) {
       int i = 23 + i;
       std::cout << "inside func, inside the if, the i here is " << i << std::endl;
    }
    return i;
}

int main() {
    int i = 15;
    if (i == 15) {
        int i = func(100);
        std::cout << "in this part of main, i is " << i << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "But in the end, the outer i is " << i << std::endl;
}
```